# next/previous word in flex builder

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, flexbuilder

The felx builder (on eclipse) next/previous word command, usually bound to CTRL-RIGHTARROW on OPTION-RIGHTARROW on the mac, doesn't stop for ":" and "." and in a few other cases.
It's clearly a wrong behaviour for action script development!
How can I change it?

Comment: It does stop at `:` and `.` for me. The only disappointment is that FB considers `camelCasedWords` as single words while eclipse treats them as separate tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix:

http://www.visible-form.com/blog/mac-eclipse-word-boundary-issue-fix/

"Go to System Preferences > Language & Text > Text, and set the ‘Word Break’ dropdown to ‘English, United States (Computer)’."

Remember Quit Flex Builder and restart it. If this doesn't work, try restarting the OS.

Answer (score 0):

This option is missing in Mavericks… you can fix it with:

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences AppleTextBreakLocale en_US_POSIX
```